# user reference field as exposed filter in view makes it very slow

Tags: views

I am using user reference field as exposed filter. The problem is that, it makes view very slow. Actually, rendering time is one minute for 100 results per page. If i remove it from filter, it goes down to about few seconds.

What can i do about it?

Comment: Do you know if the "problem" is in the query or in the rendering? (You can see the query itself by changing views advanced configuration). Do you have relashionships in that view?

Comment: I think it is in the rendering. The query itself is executed in cca 300ms.

Comment: Any custom templates / hooks / preprocesses on that view? Which formatter are you using? (Field, rendered entity..)

Comment: No, this is very simple, ordinary view with users. And i have around 6000 users ..Is this a problem?

Comment: Renering that amount of data may be a problem... Are you using pager? (How many users per page), and again - which formatter are you using?